# Why can't I localize my WPF program? I get "Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll"

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF program, and when I localize it, it fails. I created this XML namespace, which corresponds to the file location, in the `Window` element:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:ResxEditor.Properties"
```

This is how I am localizing each element:

```
<Button Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.FilePickerButton_AddFile}" />
```

The designer works perfectly fine, and I when I choose `Resources.`, auto-complete pulls up the available items, but when I build my application, it crashes with this error message:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '9'.

The line number and position correspond to the first `x` in the namespace I have given above. I tried searching this message on the web, and I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: While your question is worded and illustrated better, it is still a duplicate of the linked post. But don't worry about the dupe closure - your question still remains and it can still accumulate rep.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After an hour or so of searching the web, I randomly happened to try changing the access modifier on my Resources.resx file from `internal` to `public`.  To do so, open your .resx file in the Visual Studio editor, and change the drop-down menu labeled "Access Modifier" to "public", which should be the only other option besides "internal".

[image]

This will change all the items in the .designer file to use the `public` access modifier.  An example of these items looks like:

```
/// <summary>
///   Looks up a localized string similar to Add Files.
/// </summary>
public static string FilePickerButton_AddFile {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("FilePickerButton_AddFile", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```